# $controller is not a function error for single page applications

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I am very new to Angularjs. I have a single page application where index.html is the root page.it contains below content

**index.html**

```
//links to other pages
//ng-view
```

I have an app.js file linked to index.html which loads the respective pages when user clicks on links in index.html using ngRoute.

my app.js page looks something like this

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', [ 'ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 
    'ui.bootstrap', 'checklist-model', 'blockUI','isteven-multi-select' ]);

var App = angular.module('myApp');

//ngroute code
```

Now a page search_name.html and search_name_controller.js loaded when user clicks on one of the links in index.html

search_name_controller looks something like this.

**search_name_controller.js**

```
'use strict';

 App.controller('SearchCifCtrl', [ '$scope', '$location', '$uibModal', 
'WorkflowService', 'ConstantService', function($scope, $location, $uibModal, 
 WorkflowService, ConstantService) {

 //some code

 } ]);
```

Snce it is a single page application angular.module statement is written only in app.js file. It is not written in any other js file. Now i want to test search_name_controller.js using KARMA.I have written test code like below

**search_name_controller.test.js**

```
describe('search_name_controller', function () {

beforeEach(function() {
    module('myApp');
});

var $controller;

beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
    $controller = _$controller_;
}));

//code to test method
});
```

While i try to run this test, I am getting error as "**$controller is not a function**". i feel the error is because the  angular.module part is not defined in search_name_controller.js file. When i try to add it ,i am able to run the test.But i am not allowed to make any changes to existing code. Is there any way where my test file can read angular.module part of app.js file even if i write test scenario for search_name_controller.js.

Kindly help

Comment: Please add the script where you using the $controller in test cases script

Answer (score 0):

```
beforeEach(inject(function($controller){

   controller = $controller('SearchCifCtrl', {
    $scope: scope
  });
 }));
```

//try this to inject your controller